# Weird <br> element on Mozilla

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have this page with books and animated authors names. Theres around 35 books on the page.

http://kutsalkitap.org/kaynaklar/

When you get your mouse on a book, name of the author fades in and goes down slowly. It look perfect on chrome but, on mozilla, names goes way more down than it should be. Passes through the other books section.

When I look at the source of the page on Mozilla, I see `<br>` elements around book names which aren't there on chrome. These `<br>`'s aren't in my code.

I tried a few things but couldn't managed to fix it. Can someone help me?

Here is my code:

```css
#nav li.parent {
    margin-left: 1px;
    
    width: 740px;
    height: 130px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
}
/* Effect 9: second text and borders */
 #nav li.parent a {
    margin: 0 20px;
    padding: 18px 20px;
}
#nav li.parent a::before, #nav li.parent a::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #fff;
    content:'';
    opacity: 0.2;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, height 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s, height 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s, height 0.3s;
}
#nav li.parent a::after {
    top: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-10px);
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}
#nav li.parent a span:first-child {
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    font-weight: 300;
}
#nav li.parent a span:last-child {
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 0 0 0;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    text-shadow: none;
    text-transform: none;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    font-family: Palatino, "Palatino Linotype", "Palatino LT STD", "Book Antiqua", Georgia, serif;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    
}
#nav li.parent a:hover::before, #nav li.parent a:focus::before {
    height: 6px;
}
#nav li.parent a:hover::before, #nav li.parent a:hover::after, #nav li.parent a:focus::before, #nav li.parent a:focus::after {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    
}
#nav li.parent a:hover span:last-child, #nav li.parent a:focus span:last-child {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0%);
    transform: translateY(0%);
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="parent">
        <a href="http://www.kutsalkitap.org/allah-sevgidir">
            <span class="text1" style="color:#000;font-size:24px;">Allah Sevgidir!</span>
            <span class="text2" style="color:#000;font-size:18px;">Can Nuroğlu</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: way to much code....

Comment: `I tried a few things` show us what

Comment: Do you have an ad blocker or any other extensions installed?

Comment: Can you create a minimal runnable example that contains that problem? (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sure, here i made this minimal one example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eq54x15n/

Comment: Which is you **Firefox version**? I use 39, and it looks fine. The transition is not smooth in Firefox, but the final position is the same in Chrome 51 and Firefox 39.

Comment: The `<br>` are also in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

This will work without the `<br>` tag.

So either remove it from html or you can hide using the below css

```
span.text1 + br {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: the thing is there's not really a br tag in my code. it only appears on mozilla firefox.

Comment: I can see the <br> tag in chrome also. please add the above style and check in firefox